# nil can't be coerced into Bignum

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do Euler project 13:

> Work out the first ten digits of the sum of the following one-hundred 50-digit numbers.
>
> ```
>      list  =  [37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250,
>             46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538,
>             74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629,
>             91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250,
>             23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676,
>             89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757,
>             28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738,
>             44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318,
>             47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276,
>             70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951,
>             62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331,
>             64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178,
>             92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407,
>             58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828,
>             80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390,
>             35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586,
>             86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829,
>             71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938,
>             54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604,
>             53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145,
>             36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721,
>             45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045,
>             17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412,
>             81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692,
>             51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483,
>             62467221648435076201727918039944693004732956340691,
>             15732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209,
>             55037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126,
>             18336384825330154686196124348767681297534375946515,
>             80386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954,
>             78182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581,
>             16726320100436897842553539920931837441497806860984,
>             48403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030,
>             87086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332,
>             59959406895756536782107074926966537676326235447210,
>             69793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085,
>             41052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271,
>             65378607361501080857009149939512557028198746004375,
>             35829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307,
>             94953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275,
>             88902802571733229619176668713819931811048770190271,
>             25267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526,
>             36270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962,
>             24074486908231174977792365466257246923322810917141,
>             91430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403,
>             34413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470,
>             23053081172816430487623791969842487255036638784583,
>             11487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470,
>             63783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533,
>             67720186971698544312419572409913959008952310058822,
>             95548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774,
>             76085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236,
>             37774242535411291684276865538926205024910326572967,
>             23701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522,
>             29798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501,
>             18495701454879288984856827726077713721403798879715,
>             38298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381,
>             34829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539,
>             40957953066405232632538044100059654939159879593635,
>             29746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903,
>             41698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922,
>             62467957194401269043877107275048102390895523597457,
>             23189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519,
>             86188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672,
>             11306739708304724483816533873502340845647058077308,
>             82959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581,
>             97623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500,
>             42846280183517070527831839425882145521227251250327,
>             55121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789,
>             32238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886,
>             75506164965184775180738168837861091527357929701337,
>             62177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731,
>             32924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504,
>             99518671430235219628894890102423325116913619626622,
>             73267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724,
>             76841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818,
>             97142617910342598647204516893989422179826088076852,
>             87783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090,
>             10848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786,
>             71329612474782464538636993009049310363619763878039,
>             62184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116,
>             66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411,
>             60661826293682836764744779239180335110989069790714,
>             85786944089552990653640447425576083659976645795096,
>             66024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297,
>             64913982680032973156037120041377903785566085089252,
>             16730939319872750275468906903707539413042652315011,
>             94809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791,
>             78639167021187492431995700641917969777599028300699,
>             15368713711936614952811305876380278410754449733078,
>             40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353,
>             44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535,
>             41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954,
>             81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280,
>             82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608,
>             22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197,
>             77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617,
>             72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516,
>             20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722,
>             53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690]
> ```

Here is my code:

```
def countNumbers(list)
  value = 0
  (0..list.count).each { |y| value += list[y] }
  return value
end

puts "#{countNumbers(list)}"
```

I get: `*nil can't be coerced into Bignum*` error when I run the code.

Comment: examine values that `y` takes. You go out of bounds of the array.

Comment: ProTip: the sum can be calculated simply as `list.reduce(:+)`.

Comment: in ruby 2.4 we now have Array#sum - wohoo!

Comment: @Anthony: long overdue! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the range in `countNumbers` method.

`0..list.count` returns 0 to 100 with 100 included but `list[100]` is nil.

Change it to `0...list.count` with return 0 to 99.

See the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) to better understand using `..` and `...`